# How create .wav file with a custom frequency tone / wave?

Tags: php, audio, wav, wave

I have a problem with my wave generator. I'm trying to create a .wav file with sound of given frequency. The code I use:

```
$freqOfTone = 21000;
$sampleRate = 44100;
$samplesCount = 80000;

$amplitude = 0.25 * 32768;
$w = 2 * pi() * $freqOfTone / $sampleRate;

for ($n = 0; $n < $samplesCount; $n++)
{
    $data->samples[1][] = 32768 + (int)($amplitude *  sin($n * $w));
}
```

Unfortunately, the output wave is incorrect, I get few frequencies instead of one: http://i49.tinypic.com/ab1nx0.png

It should look like this:
http://i50.tinypic.com/33zbslk.png

Where am I doing something wrong? :(

Comment: Your code looks pretty good.  Have you considered that the problem might be with writing the data or the format of the data?  Signed vs. unsigned, bit depth, etc.

Comment: Could it be an aliasing problem due to `samplesCount` not being a multiple of wave period - try to adjust that parameter.

Comment: @moonwave99 I changed $samplesCount to 88200. It doesnt solve problem. Output file looks the same... I think count of samples shouldnt have any impact to freequency of wave.

Comment: @Sirtarius, Can you upload an example WAV file somewhere?

Comment: The point is that if you don't generate a full-period [0 to 2pi] sample of your wave, you are actually windowing it with a rectangular window, and running into [spectral leakage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage), which is what you are getting, arguing from your pics.

Comment: @moonwave: 88200 samples is two whole periods.

Comment: @Brad Yes, sure: http://www.sendspace.com/file/rkxb0z

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I know, but question provides `80k` as value - I was just explaining how windowing affects spectrum; not that I claim this to be the answer to the problem, just tried to provide an hint as a comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

Given that sample rate, the desired frequency is too close to the [Nyquist frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) to be sampled properly. I recommend you use a sample rate of 96kHz for this.

Comment: Hmm... I'd like to stay with my 44,1kHz. Is there any way to calculate nearest available frequency of tone?

Comment: To begin to have any sort of proper resolution you should have a minimum of 4 samples per period, putting you at 11.025kHz. This may seem low, but keep in mind that the bandwidth of 44.1kHz was chosen for the purpose of recording music, not for high-frequency experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved something finaly, but my solution is a little bit different from this which I meant... Anyway, I took the samples and put them through hi-pass frequency filter. Signal is a little bit distorted, but stil good enough for my purpose :)