# In Cocoa, producing a tone at given frequency for given duration

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm writing an app for mac os x that requires producing beeps at frequency specified by user, for a duration specified by the user. I searched for the answer but there are only a few code snippets for iOS and none for mac os x.

I'm new to Cocoa programming; can someone point out where I should look for the functionalities I need?

EDIT: I had checked the other answer before posting this question; the accepted answer is basically saying there's no way of doing it (which is not an answer). Also, it addresses the use of beeps as alert, but I'm not trying to alert the user.

I'm not trying to produce *one* beep; generating a .wav file doesn't help me. Consider a Morse-code generator where user gives the input and the program outputs the dit-dah-dits, except I also need the output's frequency to vary depending on user input.

Comment: Consider creading a `.wav` file with the desired frequency and length, it's quite easy to implement, checkout this Python example to get started: [How create .wav file with a custom frequency tone / wave?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761094/how-create-wav-file-with-a-custom-frequency-tone-wave)

Comment: The answer for the question that is marked as a duplicate has just been updated to include a working solution rather than a workaround.